# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2, design

My magento store is throwing this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ResolverInterface in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73

I don't know why it started to appear. I made no new module installation. The store was working fine.

I've check file permissions and I see no issue there. Also delete the /var/ dir and, I think, all folders/files where created.

[EDIT] The preference is defined vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ResolverInterface" type="Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Resolver" />
```

Comment: i hope in ur custom module or code your trying to use Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ResolverInterface in constructor or object manager

Comment: @PradeepKumar No. I'm not.

Comment: clear your cache and the contents of `var/generation`.

Comment: @Marius as stated in the question, I've already removed the /var/* folder completely.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that line.

Answer (score 74):

If you use redis, run:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

If  you  also  use  an environment like ansible (`lxc - server`), you'll need to do that command in container. Plus I did the following:

- Clear `var/generation` (or `generated/*` in newer versions)
- Clear `var/cache`
- Check if the module generating the error is enabled and enable it (`bin/magento module:enable Some_Module`) or Enable all Magento modules: `bin/magento module:enable --all`
- Compile DI `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: there were so many misleading solutions out there and this worked right away

Comment: Enable Magento modules: bin/magento module:enable --all  - Worked for me

Comment: NO! It`s not good practice! bin/magento module:enable --all is like chmod -R 777 :(

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was using a redis container. using flushall resolved the issue

Comment: flushing the redis cache solved it, even though that project has not even redis configured. I use redis for another shop though.

Comment: Thanks worked, I had to also remove directories from var/ folder

Comment: thx redis flush was the solution for me as well.

Comment: Does anyone have information on *why* this works? Why would redis be causing setup:upgrade to fail?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful

Answer (score 10):

I had this error and it was solved by clearing the var folder and then running `setup:upgrade`. If this doesn't solve it then look for errors in `di.xml` files

Comment: worked for me, specifically `var/cache`

Comment: Thanks `redis-cli flushall` worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Run following command and check.

```
rm -rf generated

rm -rf var/*
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Clear the cache
`rm -rf var/cache`

If redis enabled, clear redis db using command line:

```
$> redis-cli
$> flushall
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
 sudo apt-get install php-intl

 sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to remove a module and I simply deleted the files of the module without following proper methods and then this error was on screen everywhere. After searching much on it, I ended up placing the files of the module back to same directory and deleted all required folders from **var** and ran the following commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and all was fixed. I then followed proper ways to remove the module. Hope this saves someones time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem I was faced when updating the Magento version 2.3.3. so I replace the `app/etc/di.xml` file content help with below path. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/etc/di.xml#L212

My issue is resolved now

Answer (score 1):

This error could also because of enabling or disabling the modules directly in app/etc/config.php especially when to enable or disable core Magento modules. The best thing to do in such case would be to clear your cache, flush redis cache, restart varnish & php-fpm. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Dump **composer** **autoload** files:

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

Then:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is created when you try creating (new) an object (class) that is in fact and interface. This normally happens when you have not overridden the interface for a class in the di.xml file. Or have overridden the in the di.xml in the adminhtml directory and are trying to use the interface in the frontend.

```
interface MyInterface{
   pubic function getVariable(): int
}

class MyClass 
implements MyInterface{

   protected $variable;

   pubic function getVariable(){
      return $this->variable;
   }
}

$variable = new MyInterface();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the file `app/etc/di.xml`.

In my case I accidentially overwrote it with the file of another project.
After replacing it, it worked again!

These two lines were missing in my broken `di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    ...
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator" />
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigWriterInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator" />
```

There was also a difference in the PluginList Class:

**Broken di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
...
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config</argument>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">plugin-list</argument>
            <argument name="scopePriorityScheme" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="first" xsi:type="string">global</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
 ...
```

**Working di.xml:**

Please make sure that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
...
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config</argument>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">plugin-list</argument>
            <argument name="scopePriorityScheme" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="primary" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="first" xsi:type="string">global</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="scopePriorityScheme" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="primary" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="first" xsi:type="string">global</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also check if the module is not disabled in the config.php

```
    'Magento_Theme' => 0,
```