# Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Layer\\FilterableAttributeListInterface

Tags: magento2

I have this error:

> [Tue Dec 20 12:18:12.372646 2016] [:error] [pid 15395] [client
>   192.168.255.24:51090] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...')\n#1
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...')\n#2
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Magento\\Catalog...', NULL, 'filterableAttri...',
>   'Magento\\Catalog...')\n#3
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Catalog...',
>   Array, Array)\n#4 /var/www/magento in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 73

My code is:

```
<?php
namespace Sistel\PosicionFiltros\Block\Filtros;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filterList,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->filterList = $filterList;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getHelloWorldTxt()
    {
        $activeFilters = $this->filterList->getState()->getFilters($this->_catalogLayer);
        var_dump($activeFilters);
        exit;
        return $activeFilters;
    }
}
```

It is similar than other code in the core of magento 2. I don´t understand.

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91294/fatal-error-cannot-instantiate-interface